# Simplify a huge expression with limited memory

Tags: simplifying-expressions, summation, memory

I would like to perform some analytical sums such as the following

```
Sum[Collect[Sum[d2[r + k m, 0, r] z^(2 r + k m) I2B[(2 r + k m)/2 + 3, 2]
, {r,0, Infinity}], m, Simplify], {m, 0, Infinity}]
```

where (inserting Collect speeds it up)

```
I2B[d_,s_]:=(2 s + 1)/(4 Pi^2) (6 Exp[-1/2 t] - 
 Exp[-(d - 1) t] ((d - 3/2)^3 t^3 + 3 (d - 3/2)^2 t^2 + 
    6 (d - 3/2) t + 6))/(t^4 (1 - Exp[-t])) - (2 s + 
  1)^3/(16 Pi^2) (Exp[-t/2] - 
 Exp[-(d - 1) t] ((d - 3/2) t + 1))/(t^2 (1 - Exp[-t]))
```

and

```
d2[a_, b_, c_] := (1 + a) (1 + b) (1 + c) (1 + (a + b)/2) (1 + (b + c)/2) (1 + (a + b + c)/3)
```

I'm running this on Mathematica 8.0 installed on a Windows 7 Machine with 4 GB memory. The resulting expression is very long and when I want to FullSimplify the expression, I get the following message:

No more memory available.Mathematica kernel has shut down.Try quitting other applications and then retry.

I was wondering whether there are some clever ways to simplify the expression without causing memory leak.

Comment: Do any constraints exist for your variables.  For instance, are any known to be `Real`?

Comment: Yes there are. Sorry I did not mention them. z is a real number between zero and one. k is a positive integer and t is a positive real number.

Comment: It appears that positive `k` and `Abs[z] <1` are all that is needed for convergence.  Try the solution I proposed below, and let me know how it worked.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It is indeed faster now. However I still have trouble simplifying the resulting expression. (as you mentioned in your answer as well) Do you have any suggestions on that part?

Comment: Are you talking about the output of `Sum[is, {m, 0, Infinity}]` or of `Sum[cl[[n + 1, g + 1]] f[n, g/2], {g, 0, 2}, {n, 0, 6}]`?  Trying to `Simplify` the former is hopeless, I believe.

Comment: I guess I was talking about the former. The double sum I presented here is one of around 150 double sums that I intend to do. So I think the alternative method can still be a little bit hard to do even if it could be handled by Simplify

Comment: If all your double sums have the same general form, the procedure I described in my answer should work for all in a straightforward manner.  Directly performing the entire outer sum produces too big an expression for `Simplify` to handle.  By the way, I just corrected a minor problem with the definition of `cl`.  I also did a few spot-checks of my answer against the direct sum.  They agree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OP correctly notes that `Collect` with `Simplify` is essential for computing this double sum in a reasonable amount of time, if at all.  It is straightforward to find that the `LeafCount` of the inner sum only without using `Collect` is `721809`.  With it, the size of the inner sum drops to `21158`.  However, we can do much better.  Instead, define the inner sum as

```
is = Collect[Sum[d2[r + k m, 0, r] z^(2 r + k m) I2B[(2 r + k m)/2 + 3, 2],
    {r, 0, Infinity}] /. Exp[a_] :> Exp[Expand[a]], {m, Exp[-k m t/2]}, Simplify]
```

In other words, `Collect` over both `m` and `Exp[-k m t/2]`.  Doing so reduces the `LeafCount` to `2875`.  This factor of seven reduction probably is sufficient to perform the double sum.

```
Sum[is, {m, 0, Infinity}]
```

Using Mathematica 10.1, my computer never used more than `10%` of its `8 GB` of memory, and the total computation took only about `15` minutes.  However, the `LeafCount` of the resulting expression is `29140583`, and `Simplify` bogs down trying to reduce it.

An alternative approach to the outer sum is to decompose the outer sum into `21` sums of the form

```
Sum[m^n Exp[-g k m t] z^(k m), {m, 0, Infinity}]
```

By experimentation, I found that this expression is equal to

```
f[n_, g_] := (D[E^(k t)/(E^(k t) - z^k), {t, n}]/(-k)^n) /. t -> g t
```

Then, the solution can be found as follows.

```
cl = (CoefficientList[is, {m, Exp[-k m t/2]}] // Simplify) /. z^(k m) -> 1;
Sum[cl[[n + 1, g + 1]] f[n, g/2], {g, 0, 2}, {n, 0, 6}]
```

with a `LeafCount` of only `5767`.

**Added: Convergence Criteria**

Performing any of the `21` outer sums with `GenerateConditions -> True`, for instance,

```
Sum[m^3 Exp[-k m t] z^(k m), {m, 0, Infinity}, GenerateConditions -> True]
(* ConditionalExpression[
   (E^(k t) z^k (E^(2 k t) + 4 E^(k t) z^k + z^(2 k)))/(E^(k t) - z^k)^4,
   E^(k t) != z^k && Abs[z]^Re[k] < E^Re[k t]] *)
```

provides convergence criteria for the double sum.